# Eclipse Kepler with PDT hides my public folder

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-pdt

Since using Eclipse Kepler (with PDT) whenever I create a new PHP project, using an existing source, my 'public' folder is excluded from the Explorer view. Its not that the folder wasn't included during the Project creation though, because if I try to add it later , as a Source folder, it says it already exists!?

I've used Eclipse with PDT since E3.7 and can't work out whats going on here. Any ideas fellow Eclipse users?

Comment: I have a similar problem: My Eclipse won't show mit the /Packages folder in my project. I have no idea :-/

Comment: Still no luck for me. I'm using Laravel 4.1 php framework, by the way. I've had to resort to using a different IDE to access the Public Folder....